# Play HLS on iOS without ATS Exceptions

Tags: ios, https, http-live-streaming, app-transport-security

With the arrival of (ATS) App Transport Security enforcement for iOS apps at the end of 2016, I am trying to create a very simple iOS app based on AVPlayer able to display encrypted HLS streamed over HTTP, not HTTPS.

I found a sample app from Apple describing how to use Delegates on AVPlayer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc1791/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014357-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

The sample app, illustrate how to "intercept" media requests from AVPlayer by using custom schemes. For example, the initial playlist URL is
**cplp**://devimages.apple.com/samplecode/AVARLDelegateDemo/BipBop_gear3_segmented/redirect_prog_index.m3u8

Instead of actually requesting the .m3u8 playlist content over an http connection, the AVPlayer requests ends up in the delegate code which generates the content and returns it to the AVPlayer. **Nevertheless, the http request for the key is actually going through all the way to Apple server**

I tried the same delegation code in my app but the http request for the key is blocked by ATS.

In their project, the following call goes through:

```
[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://devimages.apple.com/samplecode/AVARLDelegateDemo/BipBop_gear3_segmented/crypt0.key"]
```

In mine, it's blocked by ATS:

```
[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:50548/proxy/session-key/?&session-id=937903260"]
```

I checked everywhere and the Apple sample app does not have any ATS exception.

Any idea why my http request are blocked?

Comment: It seems that there is an undocumented  automatic ATS exception for `http://devimages.apple.com`.  For your application you will need an ATS exception.

Comment: I'm starting a new topic on this undocumented exception at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277345/automatic-ats-exception-for-apple-com